# In logistic regression, how do I set my 'reference level' for my dummy variables in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I'm doing a logistic regression model in python using statsmodel.  Since a lot of my columns are categorical, I one-hot encoded them using "get_dummies".  My new dataframe now has a lot more columns with 1's and 0's.  (i,e gender1, gender2, stats1, status2, status 3 etc etc).

with this new dataframe, how do I set a 'reference level' for my logistic regression?  by default, how do I know what my reference level is set at?

Comment: What's a reference level? Can you provide an example?

Comment: so like when you do a logistic regression,  the coefficients indicate the magnitude in reference to the reference level.  like if you have 2 variables ('Male', 'Female', 'unknown') and if your reference level is 'Male',  the coefficient that is assigned to 'female' is the likelyhood of whatever you're predicting, in reference to the Male variable.

I'm sure I didn't explain it completly right, but I know that there does exist the idea of a reference category.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but... to set the reference level you can try the [formula api](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api.html): `statsmodels.formula.api`

The formula api uses [Patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) to turn the formula string into a dataframe (in stats terminology a design matrix) that statsmodels can use. You might also find Patsy can handle most of the data shaping you need.

To set the reference level:

```
import statsmodel.formula.api as smf

log_reg = smf.logit("y ~ C(var, Treatment(reference='reference_value'))", data=df)
```

See: [Handling Categorical Data](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html#handling-categorical-data)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% what your question is about, but in `scikit-learn` there exists the concept of a [dummy regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor.html).

If you have a dataframe df, it works like this:

```
from sklearn.dummy import DummyRegressor
clf = DummyRegressor(strategy='mean', random_state=0)
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
```

There is also the DummyClassifier with `import DummyClassifier`. Check the docs, the idea is always to predict a baseline of the mean or the most frequent category.